# Overlapping clustering

Tags: clustering, overlapping-data

It looks like "overlapping clustering" scheme where objects may belong to more than one cluster will fit my data. I've found some literature about this subject, but i'l be glad if anyone can point me to the best place to start.

My questions are:

- What are currently the state of the art algorithms, and are there
  implementations  for them (preferably for R or Python)?
- Are there relevant evaluation metrics for the result of such
  algorithms?

Comment: ELKI has a number of clustering algorithms where clusters may overlap.

Comment: What do _specifically_ you require from an overlapping clustering, some feature of an algorithm that would make it advantageous over doing usual nonoverlapping clustering and then introducing some overlap (for, you see, any nonoverlapping solution can _afterwards_ be made overlapping or vice versa - by considering borderline points).

Comment: By the way, latent variable/class models, including classic factor analysis in so called "Q mode" can br thought of as an overlapping-solution cluster analysis.

Comment: My own intuition was using a subspace of the features or a latent variable as @ttnphns mentioned in order to deal with noisy or borderline points, but i'm more interested in current works. I'l take a look at ELKI has to offer.

Comment: what does ELKI stand for

Comment: @develarist "ELKI is an open source (AGPLv3) data mining software written in Java". https://elki-project.github.io/